# How can I empty the form fields after clicking save button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to empty the form fields after clicking the save button, but am unable to do that.

Here's my complete `code`:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.oData = {};
  $scope.fnSave = function(data) {

  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control col-xs-12" type='text' ng-model="oData.name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label">Practice</label>
      <input class="form-control col-xs-12" type='text' ng-model="oData.practice" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label">designation</label>
      <input class="form-control col-xs-12" type='text' ng-model="oData.designation" required>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="fnSave(oData)">save</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Ven or maybe [they did](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/15/1599e06bd7b11b9d1e3d414c4cfb97bd3ad4ed044ac06d4ec5625cf4d0d224ec.jpg) :P

Comment: please see my edited question @Ven

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use a model object. So instead of using `$scope.firstName`, `$scope.lastName`, etc. you would use `$scope.formModel.firstName`, `$scope.formModel.lastName`, etc. Then when you want to clear things you simply use `$scope.formModel = {};` and everything is emptied out and ready for new input.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function [such as clearFields()] on clicking save button. then in clearFields() function, you can clear all ng-modal value.

Comment: But I have more form fields in my application.@Forid

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function called `clearInput()` to clear the `$scope` variables binded. Not only you can clear them, you can even set them to default values if needed. This, however requires to explicitly list down all the variables in the form you want to clear.

```
  $scope.clearInput = function(){
    $scope.firstName = "Default User"; // you can set it to empty string or default values that you want.
    $scope.lastName = ""; //an empty string means it is a clear field. 
    $scope.email = null; //alternatively you can set it to null
    $scope.address = "";
  }
```

in HTML, just declare a button that calls the function upon click, using `ng-click`:

```
<button ng-click="clearInput()">Clear Input</button>
```

Here is the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/grTayF5fA2AClch3JZF2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`ngSubmit`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive, as below:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="fnSave(oData)">
```

Then clean the whole `object` inside your `function`:

```
$scope.oData = {};
```

And finally change your `button` to:

```
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

A *snippet* working:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('plunker', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.oData = {};

    $scope.fnSave = function(data) {
      // $http.post or whatever, then clean your whole object:
      $scope.oData = {};
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello, <strong ng-bind="name"></strong>!</p>
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="fnSave(oData)">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="oData.name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="practice" class="control-label">Practice</label>
      <input type="text" id="practice" class="form-control" ng-model="oData.practice" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="designation" class="control-label">Designation</label>
      <input type="text" id="designation" class="form-control" ng-model="oData.designation" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```